# How to get the cumulative count based on other column in googlesheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I was trying to create a column with cumulative count per day from a column in google sheet but I was unable to do so.

How to get the cumulative counts?

Public spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10NzbtJhQj4hQBnZXcmwise3bLBIAWrE0qwSus_bz7a0/edit#gid=1126759670

## Question

Find cumulative number per day. Eg for May 7 start from 1,2,3 and for May 8 again start from 1,2,3 and so on.

## Required

[image]

I need the cumulative count for each day as shown in the figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In J2 I entered

```
=Arrayformula(IF(LEN(A2:A), ROW(C2:C)-MATCH(C2:C, C2:C,0),))
```

See if that works for you?

Answer (score 2):

Also

```
=ArrayFormula(if(C2:C<>"",countifs(C2:C,C2:C,row(C2:C),"<="&row(C2:C)),))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested using `gspread` module, you can get the new column as follows:

```py
import os
import glob
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import gspread

path_creds = os.path.expanduser('~/.config/gspread/credentials.json')
gc = gspread.service_account(filename=path_creds) # google service

url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10NzbtJhQj4hQBnZXcmwise3bLBIAWrE0qwSus_bz7a0/edit#gid=1126759670"

parts = url.split('/edit')
url = parts[0]
sh = gc.open_by_url(url)
ws = sh.sheet1
res = ws.get_all_records()
df = pd.DataFrame(res)
df['answer'] = df.groupby('Date')['Company'].transform('cumcount')+1
df
```

**output**

[image]